# Calculating a sum total after every n days in a table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

**New to power bi**, right now I am working with a table displaying available hours for a site on a daily basis.
What I need is to be able to add these amounts and display the total for **every 9 days**(*Don't even ask, that's their work week*)

Coming from a  java and C++ background and since I am representing a relational database (shown in a matrix) I have explored the idea of using a **loop**, a **filter** to check the days (comparing e.g. %9 == 0) or a **switch statement** as the number of weeks in a month is small.

I can't seem to wrap my head around implementing these as I have never worked with excel/DAX type code before.

**Excuse my probably awful code but I was trying to both learn the software and problem solve at the same time and thought id be better at least showing my attempts**

`Measure = CALCULATE((SUM(TABLE_NAME[hoursAvailable]))), FILTER(ALL(TABLE_NAME), TABLE_NAME[Date] = 7)`

`Measure = SUMX(FILTER(TABLE_NAME, TABLE_NAME[Date] = 9), 0)`

As I mentioned about my hope is to be able to show a total available hours per 9 days through a hopefully understandable format so I could also learn from it if possible.
Thanks

Comment: Can you show us your table(s) with some relevant data in it?

Comment: The simplest and most robust solution is to create a calendar table that contains an attribute defining a 9-day period. Very similar to "Week Number", only using 9 days instead of 7. Then connect calendar table to your main table, and you can build DAx measures and reports grouped by this 9-day attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go with the suggetion of Rado:

Create Table:

```
9WeekCalendar = CALENDAR(DATE(2019;1;1);DATE(2019;12;31))
```

Add the Column:

```
Week = 
var startDate = DATE(2019;1;1)
var week9 = ROUNDDOWN(DATEDIFF(startDate;'9WeekCalendar'[Date];DAY)/9;0)
return week9
```

This is only an example to get you going, you need to decide on the start/end date of your calendar and also need to consider if each year the weeks repeat itself or you can work with a number what is increasing over the years.